# ColdFusion 11 CFHTTP NTLM support

Tags: coldfusion, ntlm, cfhttp, coldfusion-11

In ColdFusion 11, Adobe has added `NTLM` support. However I fail to understand how I can get this working.

In particular, the documentation seems to be wrong: it states:

***For NTLM, to work, the redirect attribute must be set to false***

However, when doing so, ColdFusion throws the following exception:

> When authentication type is NTLM, redirect must not be set to false.

Has anybody got experience using `NTLM` in `CFHTTP`?

The code I am using:

```
<cfhttp url="#variables.webserviceURL#" 
        method="post" 
        result="httpResponse" 
        charset="utf-8" 
        timeout="3000" 
        authType="NTLM" 
        domain="myDomain" 
        username="myUser" 
        password="myPassword">
   <cfhttpparam type="header" name="accept-encoding" value="no-compression" />
   <cfhttpparam type="xml" value="#trim(soapRequest)#"/>
</cfhttp>
```

Comment: Can you share your code with us? Obviously do not share any actual usernames or passwords, but we need to see what you are trying in order to help.

Comment: It says here http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/security-improvements-cf11.html, how to use NTLM Authentication.

Comment: Hi Miguel, Anit. Thank you for your comments. I have added the code in the original post. I have stripped the 'redirect' attribute and we are now getting a step further: we receive a 401 code. I will look into this with our system administrator.